# file handling concept with spliting files

Tags: java

A folder contains number of text files like `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt` like that more than 30 files I need to search a particular string in the all files the output should come as follows:

> `a.txt` contains your entered string
>   20
>
> b.txt contains you entered string
>   30

And so on...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter String");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        double count = 0, countBuffer = 0, countLine = 0;
        String lineNumber = ".txt";
        File folder = new File("C://Users//Desktop//Santhosh.txt");
        BufferedReader br;
        String line = " ";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folder));
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    countLine++;
                    //System.out.println(line);
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");

                    for (String word : words) {
                        if (word.equals(input)) {
                            count++;
                            countBuffer++;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: The code you pasted isn't complete. What's not working? See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a question in order to maximize the chances of it being answered.

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting. Please add an MCVE like described by @HoriaComan and try to format it for better readability. Even if spaces are optional, they should be used...

Comment: the thing is i just need the clue for how to get the result of each text file.. i am aware of this concept..please help me

Answer (score 0):

@santhosh I think you want to search a text in files and count the occurrence of word according to file here is the program that do this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TextSearch {

  File file;
  FileReader reader;
  BufferedReader buffReader;
  String word;
  Scanner scanner;
  Map<String, Integer> counter = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

  public TextSearch() {
    file = new File("D:\\Backup\\NP\\GN");// This Contain the 30 files
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a word");
    word = scanner.nextLine();

    File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();
    startSearch(listOfFiles);

    Iterator<String> iterator = counter.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      String key = iterator.next();
      System.out.println(key + " contain this word " + word + " " + counter.get(key) + "times");
    }
  }

  public void startSearch(File[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].isFile()) {
        try {
          reader = new FileReader(list[i]);
          buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
          String line = "";
          while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(word)) {
              if (counter.containsKey(list[i].getName())) {
                Integer count = counter.get(list[i].getName());
                count++;
                counter.put(list[i].getName(), count);
              } else {
                counter.put(list[i].getName(), 1);
              }
            }
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new TextSearch();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the code is having some errors.. it is not executing

Comment: Enter a word
alpha
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.commons.io.TextSearch.startSearch(TextSearch.java:37)
 at org.apache.commons.io.TextSearch.<init>(TextSearch.java:27)
 at org.apache.commons.io.TextSearch.main(TextSearch.java:63)

Comment: this error comming while executing please checkonce and modify code

Comment: At line 37 error is come when the folder doesn't contain any file(txt).